# MongoDB in C# - Type not null query

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have collection where each document has two fields:

1. "Field1" - string value
2. "Field2" - object value with "Field2.Field3(object).Field4(string)".

Now I'm trying to take all documents for which "Field2.Field3" is not `null`. When I do sth like this for `Field1` then it works:

```
query = Builders<MyDocument>.Filter.Ne(t => t.Field1, null)
```

However, when I do the same but for "Field2.Field3":

```
query = Builders<MyDocument>.Filter.Ne(t => t.Field2.Field3, null)
```

then I got an error "command find failed". Where is the problem?

Comment: Try with: `query = Builders<MyDocument>.Filter.Ne("Field2.Field3", null)`

Comment: Try this. `Builders<MyDocument>.Filter.Ne(t => t.Field2.Field3, BsonNull.Value)`

Comment: @Gibbs I can't even create query using your solution since I got: "The type arguments for method ... cannot be inferred from the usage, try specifying the type arguments specifically"

Comment: @YongShun for your solution I got the same error as above

Comment: Can you add the complete code and stdout.

Comment: I tried to combine your solutions into 
`Builders<MyDocument>.Filter.Ne("Field2.Field3", BsonNull.Value)` but it also doesn't work

Comment: What is interesting the same problem is in Studio-3T app. I drag the field into query builder and the proposed query is `{"Field2.Field3" : {$ne : null}}` but when I run it I got "Failed to retrieve documents, no query solutions"